# C# syntax :----- IEnumerable<Person> people = new List<Person>();

Tags: c#

I understand the first two statements. However, for the third statement,  I couldn't figure out what type of the people is? IEnumerable(person) or List(person)? I assume there is a conversion behind the scenes. Can someone explain what techniques is used in Statement 3?

1. IEnumerable(Person) people = new IEnumerable(Person)();
2. List(Person) people = new List(Person)();
3. IEnumerable(Person) people = new List(Person)();

Comment: Here's a comparison on collection types, just for additional info: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/832189/List-vs-IEnumerable-vs-IQueryable-vs-ICollection-v

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = new IEnumerable<Person>();
```

Is invalid. `IEnumerable` is an *interface*, it cannot be instantiated.

The second two are valid:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
IEnumerable<Person> people = new List<Person>();
```

The second example in the above is simply casting the collection to `IEnumerable<Person>`. This means that the functionality `List` provides is *not available* unless you cast the collection back to a list. In short, that isn't really that useful. Casting to `IEnumerable` is useful when defining a method, as such:

```
void DoSomethingWithPeople(IEnumerable<Person> people)
{
    foreach(var person in people)
        Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
}
```

Here, we don't care whether the collection is a list, a set, a linked list, etc. All we care about is the fact that `people` can be enumerated (that is, it is *enumerable*).

Answer (score 0):

You really need to differentiate between the **type of the reference** and the **actual type of the object**. Have a look at this:

Real use case, if you real need to process something based on only the `number of feet` of the animals, then you can pass `Animal` References to a method taking Animal as argument, while the real object is `Animal myDogAsAnimal = new Dog();` or `Animal myOstrichAsAnimal = new Ostrich();` However, you can't access properties and methods of `Dog` and `Ostrich` without casting `(myOstrichAsAnimal as Ostrich).BuryHeadInGround();`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int convertingChartToInt = 'A'; // Valid - Covert Chart to int and store it in this variable.
        int covertDecimalToString = 5.0m; // Invalid - Convert Decimal to String and Store it in this variable.
        ICollection<String> covertListToICollection = new List<string>(); // Valid List<T> Implements ICollection<T>

        List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();
        List<Dog> myDogs = new List<Dog>();

        Animal myOstrichAsAnimal = new Ostrich();
        Animal myDogAsAnimal = new Dog();
        Dog myDogAsDog = new Dog();

        myOstrichAsAnimal.BuryHeadInGround(); // Will not Compile
        (myOstrichAsAnimal as Ostrich).BuryHeadInGround(); // Will Compile

        myDogAsAnimal.Bark(); // Will Not Compile
        myDogAsDog.Bark(); // Will Compile

        AdapotAnimal(myOstrichAsAnimal); // Will Compile

        animals.Add(myOstrichAsAnimal); // Will Compile
        animals.Add(myDogAsAnimal); // Will Compile
        animals.Add(myDogAsDog); // Will Compile

        FeedAnimals(animals); // Will Compile
    }

    private static void AdapotAnimal(Animal animal)
    {

    }

    private static void FeedAnimals(List<Animal> animals)
    {

    }
}

public class Animal
{
    public int NumberOfFeet { set; get; }
}

public class Ostrich : Animal
{
    public void BuryHeadInGround()
    {

    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public void Bark()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This are the basics of object oriented programming.

IEnumerable is an interface. It defines methods without implementing them.

List is a class and implements IEnumerable. This means it provides the implementation for the interface-methods. You can have several implementations of an interface.

Your second statement will not work anyway, because you can't make an instance (an object) of an interface, only of a concrete class.

Please read some basic books or tutorials about interfaces and oop in general

Answer (score -3):

This puts your personen object into a new list in the class person.